# Hide mobile Twitter brand bar in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, xcode, mobile, twitter, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView linking to a mobile Twitter page and it shows [this bar](http://i.imgur.com/OEdJw.jpg) at the top. I'm wanting to remove it so it won't limit viewing space but not having any luck. I have attempted to pass javascript to the page after loading to hide it but it doesn't work.

I'm using the example [here](http://dogboystudios.com/removing-html-elements-from-a-uiwebview):

```
- (void)hideUnwantedHTML{

[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var script = document.createElement('script');"  

    "script.type = 'text/javascript';"  

    "script.text = \"function hideID(idName) { "  

    "var id = document.getElementById(idName);"  

    "id.style.display = 'none';"

 "}\";" 



 "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);"];  

[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"hideID('brand_bar');"];    
}
```

And:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

[self hideUnwantedHTML];

}
```

I've also tried it with getElementByClassName and getElementByTagName and none work. Any ideas?